# How can I remove a google calendar from list of calendars on BQ ubuntuphone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, calendar

The Ubuntu phone is improving at each update.

By the way I added different google calendars to the canonical calendar app and now I'm not able to remove them as I experience synchro problems with some of them.

I can disable them, but not remove them. I tried uninstalling/reinstalling the app, but they appear again.

I hope that there will be soon the opportunity to add Caldav calendars.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the corresponding Google account from `System Settings > Accounts`, then add the account again but don't allow the Calendar app to access the account.